# Python Telegram Bot - Calling variable in URL?

Tags: python, url, bots, telegram, sendmessage

am having difficulty calling a variable as part of the url in a message I intend to send via the Python Telegram bot. Due to the nature of my code, the 'webpage' variable varies and the url has to be called as a variable. Placing the `url' variable in curly brackets did not work and some searching online has been in vain. Appreciate any pointers.

```
webpage = "abc"
url = "https://www.example.com/" + webpage
message = *Website*: " + "[click here]({url})"
parse_mode = 'markdown'
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}&parse_mode={parse_mode}"
requests.get(url).json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
message = f"*Website*: [click here]({url})"
```

The `f` before the `"` causes the `{url}` to be parsed, otherwise it is handled as a simple string and `{}` are not getting replaced.

You can read more details about "Formatted String Literals" or simple "f-strings", e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)